# android Orientation of screen creating problem

Tags: android

I have created an App, when my app start its shows a image and I have set ScreenOrientation="sensor" in manifest.

but when I rotate my device my app crashes.

sometime its shows image in portrait mode or landscape mode.

can anybody please help me.

how can I set orientation of screen according to sensor.

Thanks

Comment: Post your logcat of the error.

Comment: r u used thread in your activity?>??

Comment: Hi..samir see I used thread in my first Splash Screen after that my second screen is come where i didn't use thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your activity in your Manifest file is::
 and also stop or intrupted yout thread while completing the work

Main problem is your background Thread is running and when you change orientation the new view is generated and try to access old view so app crashes....

```
<activity android:name=".SensorTest"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"  android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```